# SQL Query using GROUP BY Statment

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this table in my database:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ Name  ║ Price ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ ciao  ║   123 ║
║  2 ║ ciao  ║    55 ║
║  3 ║ bye   ║    43 ║
║  4 ║ hello ║    12 ║
║  5 ║ ciao  ║     1 ║
║  6 ║ ciao  ║    77 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

..and i wound like to create a new view displaying two columns:

1) "ciao" or "not ciao"

2) how many rows in the previous table are "ciao" or "not ciao", something like this:

```
╔════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║   Name   ║ Count ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ ciao     ║     4 ║
║  2 ║ not ciao ║     2 ║
╚════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

I'm trying to find a solution, but i'm not able to group by "not ciao" values:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) 
FROM mytable
WHERE Name = "Ciao"
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work (not tested) :

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN name = 'ciao' THEN 'ciao'
         ELSE 'not ciao'
       END as NAME,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   table
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN name = 'ciao' THEN 'ciao'
            ELSE 'not ciao'
          END
```

OR in MySQL

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN name = 'ciao' THEN 'ciao'
         ELSE 'not ciao'
       END as NAME1,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   table
GROUP  BY NAME1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to map everything except `'ciao'` to `'not ciao'`, like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Name!='ciao' THEN 'not ciao' ELSE Name END as Name, COUNT(*) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Name!='ciao' THEN 'not ciao' ELSE Name END
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) 
FROM
(select case when name <> "Ciao" then "Not Ciao"
                  else "Ciao" end as name
 from mytable)
GROUP BY Name
```